# reduce matrix by resize submatrix - OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

i need to reduce a matrix (from image) using "resize" function on submatrices.

in a loop, i create submatrices wrt a "Ray", then i have a submatrices with Ray rows and Ray cols.

when i call the Resize method on submatrices, it's only accept submatrices of ray 1,2,4,8. I need to reduce submatrices of any ray.

here the code:

```
Mat img, result;
int ray = atoi(argv[2]);
int ptR, ptC,m=0,n=0;
img = imread(argv[1],IMREAD_COLOR);
result.create(img.size()/ray, img.type());
if(ray>=result.rows || ray >= result.cols){
    cerr << "Ray too high. Break.\n";
    return -1;
}
for(unsigned int i=0; i<img.rows; i+=ray){
    if((img.rows-i)<ray) ptR = img.rows-i;
        else ptR = ray;
    for (unsigned int j=0; j<img.cols; j+=ray){
        if((img.cols-j)<ray) ptC = img.cols-j;
            else ptC = ray;          
        resize(img(Rect(j,i,ptC,ptR)), result.row(m).col(n) ,result.row(m).col(n).size());
        n++;   
    }n=0;m++;
}
```

if i instantiate the program with ray 5 or 7 or 6, the error reported in execution is

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= _colRange.start && _colRange.start <= _colRange.end && _colRange.end <= m.cols) in Mat, file /Users/Maurizio/Desktop/SPM/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 477
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /Users/Maurizio/Desktop/SPM/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:477: error: (-215) 0 <= _colRange.start && _colRange.start <= _colRange.end && _colRange.end <= m.cols in function Mat

Abort trap: 6

Comment: Ehm... Could you be a little more clear?

Comment: Yes, i'll edit just now!! :) Sorry!

Comment: can you print source and destination sizes to find out whether bad sizes (like 0) are within your resize call?

Comment: yes, but src is [3x3] and dst is [1x1]

here's the print:
`size is[3 x 3] and [1 x 1]
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= _colRange.start && _colRange.start <= _colRange.end && _colRange.end <= m.cols) in Mat, file /Users/Maurizio/Desktop/SPM/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 477
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /Users/Maurizio/Desktop/SPM/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:477: error: (-215) 0 <= _colRange.start && _colRange.start <= _colRange.end && _colRange.end <= m.cols in function Mat`